# Why do some Chrome VPN extensions not work?

Tags: google-chrome, vpn, google-chrome-extensions, privacy-protection, privacy-extensions

I have tried a number of free Chrome VPN extensions on a Windows desktop PC.  I found all were successful in providing a different IP address.  However, with almost half of the VPNs, I worryingly found that my ISP could still track (and block) sites I was visiting - even though I was connected to the VPN!  Therefore, it looks like these VPNs are not fully encrypting the connection, and are leaking some information.  Could you please advise why this is, and is there any way to resolve?  Why do some work but not others?  What are they doing differently?  Can anyone analyse the network traffic to see why they don't work?

Working VPN Chrome Extensions (traffic cannot be tracked/blocked by ISP):

- Browsec
- CyberGhost
- DotVPN
- FreeMyBrowser
- Hotspot Shield
- SkyZIP
- ZenMate

Non-Working VPN Chrome Extensions (traffic can be tracked/blocked by ISP):

- Betternet
- Hideninja
- TorVik
- Wallcy
- Zapyo